# SVN & Apache via WebDAV

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, webdav

I'm trying to configure Apache to run with SVN. This works pretty well except the authentication.

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2
apache2: Syntax error on line 185 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so: undefined symbol: dav_svn_split_uri
[fail]
```

Well I checked back the config-file he's complaining about:

```
root@uxserver:/etc/apache2# cat mods-enabled/authz_svn.load
LoadModule authz_svn /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

I needed to build that file myself as it wasn't available after installing `libapache2-svn` package.
The machine's running Ubuntu and SVN itself works. Here's my...

```
root@uxserver:/etc/apache2# ls mods-enabled/
alias.conf          authz_groupfile.load  autoindex.load  dav.load       deflate.load mime.conf         proxy_http.load  ssl.conf
alias.load          authz_host.load       cgid.conf       dav_lock.load  dir.conf      mime.load         proxy.load       ssl.load
auth_basic.load     authz_svn.load        cgid.load       dav_svn.conf   dir.load      negotiation.conf  rewrite.load     status.conf
authn_file.load     authz_user.load       dav_fs.conf     dav_svn.load   env.load      negotiation.load  setenvif.conf    status.load
authz_default.load  autoindex.conf        dav_fs.load     deflate.conf   headers.load  proxy.conf        setenvif.load
```

When googling around I found that the order in which the modules are loaded could be wrong. But I cannot really influence this one. I even tried to rename the file `authz_svn.load` to `zauthz_svn.load` in order to have it loaded at last, which didn't work either.

Any idea? Or is there any other way to have apache use the same authentication like `svnserve`, because I have already an svnserve running correctly. And I would like to attach apache to this same repos.

Little Note: The repos is accessible only through SSL, forced by

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /media/data/svn/
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /media/data/svn/conf/authz
</Location>
```

in the file for vhosts.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Ubuntu, it should work. I installed the libapache2-svn a long time ago and it installed mod_authz_svn.so to my system.

Here is my dav_svn.load

root@rhea:~# cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.load
# Depends: dav
LoadModule dav_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so

Want me to attach my mod_authz_svn.so somehow so you can see if that will work for you?
Perhaps you just need to enable mod_dav_svn.so?

Comment: Thanks for your very fast reply. You helped me finding the solution even without telling me what the problem was :D As you post the file `davn_svn.load` I wonder that the authz_svn_module is loaded here as well... Removed the file I've created on my own (`authz_svn.load`, see post) and now it works. darn. thanks again!

Comment: +1: cannot vote up yet, would do it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `a2enmod modulename` command on Ubuntu to enable apache modules in the future. It will take care of everything, including the *.load files. No need to hand edit those at all.